# How to use Escape Key to end a Loop in C

Tags: c, loops, getch

I just want to end a do while loop in C like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    char exit;
    do{
        printf("PLEASE INSERT OPTION:");
        exit = getchar();
    }while(exit != '\027');

}//main
```

I think it is kind of this way.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @DrewMcGowen *How to use Escape Key to end a Loop in C*

Comment: Don't use a variable called `exit`; there's a function called `exit()` too and you would not be able to use it in a function that has a local variable called `exit`.  A global variable called `exit` would be even worse.

Comment: @2501 perhaps it could be stated more clearly - as it stands, OP has provided code that seems to answer the question, so it's not clear what's *really* being asked.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen The question is there, but it is unclear to you, shouldn't you then ask that.

Comment: @2501 I'm not the one asking the question, and while I could edit it to clarify it, I don't want to risk asking the wrong question.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Actually you were asking a question: *What's the question?*, while the question is there, you should really ask: *Your question is unclear to me, please elaborate( or something )*

Comment: @2501 fair enough (I would edit my original comment, but it's been more than 5 minutes)

Comment: Ok I just want to end a loop while pressing the Escape Key. I've tried the code above but the loop never ends.

Comment: Note: If the EOF condition occurred (e.g. pressing Ctrl-D), code would be stuck in an infinite loop.  Better to use `}while(exit != 27 && exit != EOF);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`27` is the decimal ASCII value for Escape, but you use an octal character code. You should say `27`, or `'\033'` (or `'\x1b'` for hex which is more common). This might be the problem, assuming your terminal lets through the Escape character. Sometimes they're used for terminal-level magic, and thus "eaten" by the terminal.

Also, please note that `getchar()`, despite its name, returns `int` and **not** `char`. It can also return the non-character value `EOF` (if you hit <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> (in Unix)) so a larger type is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found the problem, look this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


main()
{
int exit;
do{
     printf("PLEASE INSERT OPTION:");
exit = getch();

}while(exit != 27);

}//main
```

That worked. Thanks for the help.
@MichaelWalz @DrewMcGowen @2501 @unwind