# C program terminate while press escape

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop, terminate

I am a beginner in C.  I wrote a C program in Code::Blocks on Windows which will take a `int` input and print it on the next line.  I want to run the loop until I press escape, but I can not do that. My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int k;
    do {
        scanf("%d",&k);
        printf("%d\n", k);      // print  value
    } while (k != 27);          // end when Esc pressed

    return 0;
}
```

The loop is working.  I input an integer and it prints it on the next line.  But it is not terminating by pressing the escape key. There is nothing when I press Escape. I want to run the program until I press the escape, while still accepting `int`-type inputs from the user.  How can I terminate the program on pressing escape?

Comment: "There is nothing when I press Escape" --> post the sample input used - every key pressed would help.

Comment: [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35954128/2877364), and a possibly-useful [search result](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120819083250AAcUZia&guccounter=1)

Comment: This was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20579502/the-c-program-should-exit-as-soon-as-he-presses-esc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Escape Key to end a Loop in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783701/how-to-use-escape-key-to-end-a-loop-in-c)

Comment: @imans77 I don't think that's a duplicate, since it doesn't include `scanf`.  I can't find an exact duplicate (though I may be missing it).  **Md. Shamvil Hossain,** what OS and compiler are you using?  Some of the answers are platform-specific.

Comment: I am using windows and compiler is codeblocks

Comment: @cxw of course it doesn't include scanf because scanf wouldn't work.

Comment: @cxw So I thought it was a duplicate because I thought what he was trying to achieve was ending the loop **without buffer**. which the `scanf` can't handle, so he must use another buffer-free stuff like `getchar` or something. That was my opinion about it :-?

Comment: @cxw the question is about how to do it, not about how to do it with scanf.

Comment: The real answer to this question is "don't, it's not a beginner's task".

Comment: This has nothing to do with scanf.  To expand on n.m.'s comment (that this is not a beginner's task), you need to realize that hitting the escape key sends an interrupt to the OS but sends no information at all to your program.  To get that information, you will need to do different things depending on the platform you're running on.  (There are libraries that abstract away the differences, however.)  Rather than aborting on `esc` it would be easier to terminate the program on end of input.  Not only is that easier, it is also more idiomatic and more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the function `kbhit();` and `getch();`

A possible solution would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){

char ch;
int k;
while (1) {

    if (kbhit) {

        scanf("%d",&k);
        printf("%d\n", k); 

        // Stores the pressed key in ch
        ch = getch();

        // Terminates the loop
        // when escape is pressed
        if (int(ch) == 27)
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide full program please??

Comment: @Md.ShamvilHossain I did, I am currently on my Smartphone so I am not able to check my code above (but it should work).